# How to access props.history.push("/some-route") inside BrowserRouter, but outside of Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to use `props.history` inside `BrowserRouter`(imported BrowserRouter as Router) but outside of `Route`. I'm getting error - *TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined*
. Is there any way?

```
import React from "react";
import Home from "../../pages/Home";
import Signup from "../../pages/Signup";
import Login from "../../pages/Login";
import { Navbar, Nav, Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
} from "react-router-dom";
import auth from "../auth/auth";

const NavBar = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar bg="light" variant="light" sticky="top">
        <Container>
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            <Link to="/" className="nav-link" id="site-logo">
              Logo
            </Link>
            <Link to="/my-account" className="nav-link push">
              My Account
            </Link>
            {
              // show logout button only if logged in
              auth.isAutheticated ? (
                <button
                  onClick={() =>
                    auth.logout(() => {
                      props.history.push("/");
                    })
                  }
                >
                  Logout
                </button>
              ) : null
            }
          </Nav>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/signup">
          <Signup />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login">
          <Login />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Comment: try to create a separate component for NavbarContainer and inside it use hook `useHistory` it should work

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory

Comment: any alternative of `useHistory` for class components?

Comment: withRouter https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter